# working with php if statement

Tags: php, if-statement

I have the following PHP IF statements

```
<?php
if ($crs_cat1 == "Business"){
  $catimage ="businessImage.png";
}
else if ($crs_cat1 == "Leadership") {
  $catimage = "leadershipImage.png"; 
}

else if ($crs_cat1 == "Media and Design") {
  $catimage = "mediadesignImage.png"; 
}

else if ($crs_cat1 == "Web Development") {
  $catimage = "webdevelopmentImage.png"; 
}

else if ($crs_cat1 == "Mobile Development") {
  $catimage = "mobileDevelopment.png"; 
}

else if ($crs_cat1 == "Project Management") {
  $catimage = "business5.png"; 
}

else if ($crs_cat1 == "Databases and Business Intelligence") {
  $catimage = "businessAnalysis.png"; 
}

else if ($crs_cat1 == "IT Service Management") {
  $catimage = "itService.png"; 
}

else if ($crs_cat1 == "Business Analysis and Agile") {
  $catimage = "businessAnalysis.png"; 
}

else if ($crs_cat1 == "Network Security and OS") {
  $catimage = "networkSecurity.png"; 
}

else if ($crs_cat1 == "Virtualization and Cloud Computing") {
  $catimage = "virtualization.png"; 
}

else if ($crs_cat1 == "Software Quality & Testing Tools") {
  $catimage = "testing.jpg"; 
}

else if ($crs_cat1 == "Microsoft") {
  $catimage = "microsoft2.png"; 
}

else if ($crs_cat1 == "%Adobe%") {
  $catimage = "adobe.png"; 
}

else if ($crs_cat1 == "IBM") {
  $catimage = "ibm.jpg"; 
}

else {
    $catimage = "negotiation.png"; 

}






?>
```

In the if statements I would like to be more like if its like Business or leadership, in the sense the result doesn't have to be exact it just has to be similar enough. For instance if == to adobe, and the title is adobe dreamweaver, than it should populate

Comment: you want regular expressions then

Comment: you mean crs_cat = "string" righjt

Comment: http://php.net/strpos

Comment: i was thinking  `preg_match`

Comment: @Dagon or *Match Game*.

Comment: i figure if he's asking the question, the str* functions are easier to wrap your head around for beginners

Comment: `if (preg_match("/Business|leadership/i", $crs_cat1)) {`....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you use stripos(), or preg_match(). You can also use strpos() IF you know the case of the text you are matching is definitely going to match, IE Business, not business or BUSINESS

If you can match case *sensitively* you can save some execution time, but if it's user input, you should take match case *insensitively*.

**To match case-senstively with stripos():**

```
if(strpos($crs_cat1, 'Business') !== FALSE){ //code }
```

**To match case-sensitvely with regular expression:**

```
if(preg_match('/Business/', $crs_cat1)){ //code }
```

**OR, to match case-INsensitvely (recommended usually):**

```
if(stripos($crs_cat1, 'Business') !== FALSE){ //code }
```

**OR, to match case-INsensitvely with regex:**

```
if(preg_match('/business/i', $crs_cat1)){ //code }
```

Typically, if you're matching on a simple string like in your example, you should stick to strpos/stripos. BUT, if you're matching on any complex type of match, preg_match is of great use.

I recently ran a performance test betweeen stripos and preg_match to confirm stripos() is still faster for a simple word match.

**stripos() 10000000 iterations:**

```
6.687420129776s
```

**preg_match() 10000000 iterations:**

```
9.2206559181213s
```

*RoCksFrow*

Answer (score 0):

You could just do a simple substring match on "Business" or "Leadership" with strpos. That will find an occurrence of any "Business" substring in the string variable.

```
if (strpos($crs_cat1, "Business") !== false) {
    $catimage = "businessAnalysis.png"; 
}
```

Just make sure you are checking with "!== false", not "true" or "!false" or anything else as the return value is actually type dependent.

See http://php.net/strpos for further reference.

Also, worth noting that `stripos` will search on the substring not worrying about the case (case insensitive). http://php.net/stripos